# I want to use Anylogic as a visualization tool for a big log file? Is it possible?

Tags: anylogic

I asked a similar question to Anylogic linkedin forum so sorry for multiple posting (possibly for some of you). I just heard about the Anylogic program. My purpose is not simulation I want to visualize a log file. I want to allow the admin-user (who will be the user of the Anylogic model) to enter some settings which will cause some filtering and I want to visualize the whole file with Anylogic.

The file is a communication file. Possibly I will show communication attendees and interactions using Anylogic. I want to emphasize unnormal patterns in the log using visual and interactive properties of Anylogic. There may also some need for like zooming in and out during the execution of the model.

Is it something very difficult to do? I am a Java developer. I can understand that I should have to learn Anylogic. What other skills and development and test environments (Ide etc.) do I need?

I plan to do a serial of implementations for several log file types and currently I am trying to find the best tool which will allow me to make changes in visualization part of the models easily till I find the best representation of the data.

There are some examples of Anylogic which are installed built-in  but I couldn't see an example which suits my situation. I do not know where to start. If someone helps me to start the design I would be very happy :)
Thank you for your attention..

Edit:
I am attaching a sample stereoscopic view model and a sample view. I want to do something similar to this. Is it ok with AnyLogic?

[image]

[image]
Ferda

Answer (score 0):

simple answer: yes its possible.

Some more comments:

I am currently working on a very similar project actually. For me as an experienced AnyLogic user, it is very natural and AnyLogic offers all the features you ask for.

> Is it something very difficult to do?

That depends on how quickly you can learn AL. But if you are experienced with Java, it will not be too hard, I imagine.

> What other skills and development and test environments (Ide etc.) do I need?

None, really. You need to figure out how to use the visual elements of AL. All of them can be changed statically via the AL IDE but you can always change them dynamically via Java code. That is very important to realize and play around with.

> I am attaching a sample stereoscopic view model and a sample view. I want to do something similar to this. Is it ok with AnyLogic?

Yes, that can be done.

I suggest you try checking the example models that come with AL. If you find something that looks like what you need, try to figure out how they did it. Then try to recreate it in a simple example model for yourself.